# Showing only current selection of an array in appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, append

In the snippet below, I am checking for the data attribute `cal-choice` and then removing a class before appending to `pg-img-review`. The issue I am having figuring out is how to only show the current selection. If you check a box and then uncheck it, the text still remains.

Another thing is I only want one to show, but keep the checkboxes as checkboxes (not radio buttons).

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong or need to do?

```js
$('body').on('change', '.option-check', function() {
  var lim = 1;
  var calPrevImg = [];
  $('.option-check:checked').each(function() {
    calPrevImg.push($($(this).data('cal-choice')));
    for (var i = 0, len = calPrevImg.length; i < len; i++) {
      calPrevImg[i].removeClass('cal-selected-img').appendTo('#pg-img-review');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.cal-selected-img {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.small {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="option-check" data-cal-choice="<div class='cal-selected-img small'>Hello</div>">
<input type="checkbox" class="option-check" data-cal-choice="<div class='cal-selected-img small'>
Goodbye</div>">
<div id="pg-img-review"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rearranged some of your code. I added a wipe the current contents and then I moved the for loop out to avoid repetitive adding. I'm 90% sure this is desired behavior, comment if it isn't.

```js
$('body').on('change', '.option-check', function() {
  var lim = 1;
  var calPrevImg = [];
  $('.option-check:checked').each(function() {
    calPrevImg.push($($(this).data('cal-choice')));
  });
  $('#pg-img-review').html("");
for (var i = 0, len = calPrevImg.length; i < len; i++) {
    calPrevImg[i].removeClass('cal-selected-img').appendTo('#pg-img-review');
  }
});
```

```css
.cal-selected-img {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.small {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="option-check" data-cal-choice="<div class='cal-selected-img small'>Hello</div>">
<input type="checkbox" class="option-check" data-cal-choice="<div class='cal-selected-img small'>
Goodbye</div>">
<div id="pg-img-review"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help. This is perfect!